# Installing Magento 2 Store

Tags: magento2, installation, linux

I am trying to install a Magento 2 store in a Ubuntu instance of AWS.

I am getting broken site like below

[image]

I used below commands

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

I got below text in **system.log** file

```
[2018-11-07 12:04:30] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
[2018-11-07 12:08:58] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
[2018-11-07 12:19:04] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
[2018-11-07 12:39:42] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
[2018-11-07 12:41:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't ex$
[2018-11-07 12:41:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist$
[2018-11-07 12:41:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] $
[2018-11-07 12:41:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't $
[2018-11-07 12:41:53] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-11-07 12:43:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't ex$
[2018-11-07 12:43:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist$
[2018-11-07 12:43:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] $
[2018-11-07 12:43:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't $
[2018-11-07 12:43:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

I got below output in **exception.log** file

```
[2018-11-07 12:04:30] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-o$
[2018-11-07 12:08:58] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-o$
[2018-11-07 12:19:04] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-o$
[2018-11-07 12:39:42] main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/.
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.$
Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-o$
```

What is the solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

there is directory permission issue you may run this command in linux terminal and try

sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Ayaz for your reply. I tried your command but get not result. Now I used `php bin/magento setup:upgrade
` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`  and got output `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''extensionActio' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ')' in /var/www/html/generated/metadata/global.php on line 112846`. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to upload my Store again. Could you please say which commands should I run from the beginning ?

Comment: Which version of magento your using? how you did installed the magento by composer or manual?

Comment: I am using Magento 2. I installed manually. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Ayaz, I installed in localhost and it is working fine in localhost.

Comment: are you using magento 2 latest version 2.2.6?

Comment: @abuabu , glad you fixed it!

Comment: No, It is not fixed so far.

Comment: Alright, what issue now your facing?

Comment: I am getting this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMmQg.png. Thanks

Comment: Run these commands  in your site root 

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo chmod 777 -R pub/static/

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Ayaz. Now I am getting broken site.

Comment: Okay , share the screenshot of header css paths

Comment: if there is version number in the path css file path then we need to fix that path. i.e in header css file paths look like (/pub/static/frontend/***/default/en_US/version_122545/xyx.css)

Comment: Here is the links of CSS.

`<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://mouse.com/pub/static/version1541601908/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />`
`<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://mouse.com/pub/static/version1541601908/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css" />`
`<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://mouse.com/pub/static/version1541601908/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css" />`

Comment: open your magento database and run this query to remove version number from the path

(insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0); )

after this  clear cache 

(rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*)

than deploy static content

(php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Muhammad Ayaz. I am getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tszne.png

Comment: sudo chmod 777 -R var pub/static

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working perfectly now. You are **Magenius** . Thanks.

Comment: Very glade you got it fix!

Comment: But I can't see Admin Panel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ2PO.png

Comment: Just copy pub/.htaccess to magento root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85454/discussion-between-muhammad-ayaz-and-abu-abu).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85464/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammad-ayaz-installing-magento-2-store).